# Product-preserving fibrant replacement functor for the Joyal model structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

There are a few fibrant replacement functors for the Quillen model structure on simplicial sets that preserve finite cartesian products, namely $\operatorname{Ex}^\infty$ and $\operatorname{Sing}(|\cdot|)$.  Does there exist a product-preserving functorial fibrant replacement for the Joyal model structure?

Comment: At any rate, there's no fibrant replacement functor which preserves finite limits and fibrations -- if there were, then the same argument as for the Quillen model structure would show the Joyal model structure to be right proper, which it's not.

Comment: @TimCampion Lurie seems to use the fibrant replacement to ensure that his construction of the Yoneda embedding is a simplicial functor in 5.1.3 of HTT.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't read that bit of HTT before. I don't understand how that's relevant.